# Reducing space between first and last name in casual moderncv template

Tags: spacing, titles, moderncv, cv

I'm converting my resume into the `moderncv` casual template. I came across a [couple](http://alexkrispin.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cv_moderncv1.png) [examples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4025249/stefanie_cv/cv_stefanie_v3b.pdf) of this template in action that I quite liked. However, when I started using it, I noticed the space between my two names in the heading is much larger than what the examples show. I'd much prefer to have it back the old way.

I saw in the [`CHANGELOG`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/CHANGELOG) that in version 1.2.0, the `\makecvtitle` code was changed for the casual template to fix some alignment issues. I'm guessing that's where this change was introduced, as I believe the two examples I was looking at are older. Is there a simple way I could change the title formatting to reduce the space between the two names? Any suggestions you have would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The space between the `\firstname` and `\lastname` is set in `\makecvtitle`. Here's the code from [`moderncvstylecasual.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylecasual.sty):

```
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % ensure footer with personal information
  \makecvfooter%
  % optional picture
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  % name
  \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
  \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
    \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}\\[-.35em]% alternate design: \MakeLowercase and no space
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% \null is required as there is no box on the line after \\, so glue (and leaders) disappears; this is in contrast to after \par, where the next line starts with an indent box (even after \noindent).
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
```

The lines of interest are

```
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
    \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}\\[-.35em]% alternate design: \MakeLowercase and no space
```

where `\@firstname` is set with colour `color2!50` (50% of `color2`) and `\@lastname` is set with colour `color2` (full "strength" of `color2`). Note the space between the two. That's a regular interword space; here's a visual when compiling [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) under the `casual` style:

[image]

The simplest way to adjust the spacing is to include any adjustment in the `\firstname` macro itself:

```
\firstname{John\hspace{-.1em}}
```

If you're using a cover letter as part of your resume, you may want to re-issue the `\firstname` there in its correct/proper form, otherwise the adjustment will be used there as well.

Here is a complete example from `template.tex` (with an emphasized `-.5em` adjustment):

[image]

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2012 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'


% moderncv themes
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}    % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                         % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}        % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\firstname{John\hspace{-.5em}}% Adjust spacing between first and last name
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                        % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}            % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                  % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted
\quote{Some quote (optional)}                 % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                     % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}            % change the symbol for lists

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% for BibTeX numerical labels
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\firstname{John}% Correct first/last name spacing in cover letter

\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                         % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```